# I get a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException while using substring in Android Studio

Tags: android, string, android-studio

This line of code puts my three inputs for a phone number( the inputs split he phone number into area code, first three digits and the following four digits) into a string fullPhoneNumber. I looked through a few answers before asking but I couldn't adapt them to my code.

```
fullPhoneNumber = areaCodeInput.getText().toString() + firstThreeDigitsInput.getText().toString() + finalFourDigitsInput.getText().toString();
```

Next this code enters the full string into a database.

```
 LoginEntries newPhoneNumber = new LoginEntries("", "", "", "","", fullPhoneNumber);
```

This piece of code is called when i want to print the phone number in an activity. I use substring in this method the display the phone number in the format(888)-888-8888. But there is always an error. dbString = '(' + holder.substring( 1, 3) + ')' + '-' + holder.substring(4, 3) + '-' + holder.substring(7, 4);

```
public String phoneNumberDatabaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES + " WHERE 1";

    //cursor point to a location in your results
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PHONENUMBER)) != null){
            String holder = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PHONENUMBER));
            dbString = '(' + holder.substring( 1, 3) + ')' + '-' + holder.substring(4, 3) + '-' + holder.substring(7, 4);
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    c.close();
    return dbString;
}
```

This is the error if I try the substring as I found it on stackoverflow.

```
     Process: com.example.vitaliy_2.emailpassworddatabasetrial, PID: 17397
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5191)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20916)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5191)                                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20916) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)                                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972                                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; regionStart=4; regionLength=-1
at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:504)
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1333)
at com.example.vitaliy_2.emailpassworddatabasetrial.EmailDBHandler.phoneNumberDatabaseToString(EmailDBHandler.java:257)
    at com.example.vitaliy_2.emailpassworddatabasetrial.SignUpMainClass.printDatabase(SignUpMainClass.java:183)
    at com.example.vitaliy_2.emailpassworddatabasetrial.SignUpMainClass.registerAccount(SignUpMainClass.java:153)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5191) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20916)                                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)                                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.Zyg`enter code here`oteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

I changed the code a bit hoping it would help but to no avail. dbString = '(' + holder.substring( 1, 3) + ')' + '-' + holder.substring(4, 6) + '-' + holder.substring(7, 10);

```
 public String phoneNumberDatabaseToString(){
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES + " WHERE 1";

        //cursor point to a location in your results
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PHONENUMBER)) != null){
                String holder = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PHONENUMBER));
                dbString = '(' + holder.substring( 1, 3) + ')' + '-' + holder.substring(4, 6) + '-' + holder.substring(7, 10);
                dbString += "\n";
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        db.close();
        c.close();
        return dbString;
    }
```

This is the error I get from this particular code.

```
Process: com.example.vitaliy_2.emailpassworddatabasetrial, PID: 11254
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5191)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20916)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5191) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20916) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; regionStart=4; regionLength=-1
at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:504)
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1333)
at com.example.vitaliy_2.emailpassworddatabasetrial.EmailDBHandler.phoneNumberDatabaseToString(EmailDBHandler.java:257)
at com.example.vitaliy_2.emailpassworddatabasetrial.SignUpMainClass.printDatabase(SignUpMainClass.java:183)
at com.example.vitaliy_2.emailpassworddatabasetrial.SignUpMainClass.registerAccount(SignUpMainClass.java:153)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5191) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20916) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the method description carefully. [String.substring (int start, int end)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) parameters are `start` and `end`, not `start` and `length`.
So using it as 
 `holder.substring(4, 3)` you try to take substring starting at 4th, and ending at 3rd char, the length of this substring naturally is -1

Comment: I had that thought when I was looking up info on substring, and I tried different combos of operations, none work. I corrected for the string index and the other answer suggested and gave that a try, still nothing. Maybe the error is in another part of the program.

Comment: @VitaliyDvorkin, looks like it didn't build new sources, since the exception is the same. Also what is located at EmailDBHandler.java:257 (257th line)?

Comment: the 257th line had the substring code. After eliminating a few more potential locations for errors, It seems that when the phonenumber is called from it's location from my database it acquires character spaces so it doesn't equal the 10 digits of a phone number.

Comment: dbString = '(' + holder.substring( 1, 3) + ')' + '-' + holder.substring(4, 6) + '-' + holder.substring(7, 10);
 this is what the line of code looks like now

Answer (score 0):

String index is 0 based, holder.substring( 1, 3) should be holder.substring(0, 3) etc. (The first parameter is inclusive and second parameter is exclusive to 0 - 3 means it will get index 0, 1 and 2)

Comment: dbString = '(' + holder.substring( 0, 2) + ')' + '-' + holder.substring(3, 5) + '-' + holder.substring(6, 9); did this,
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=2
got this

Comment: Did you check to see that the string has the number of characters you expect before running that code fragment - can't rely on values you're getting back all being good.

Comment: wrote some code to check. It does not. huh. 
fullPhoneNumber = areaCodeInput.getText().toString() + firstThreeDigitsInput.getText().toString() + finalFourDigitsInput.getText().toString();
how does this line add two extra chars to my string?
thank you for your help

Comment: I just found my mistake. I should stop coding after midnight